# Craft 3, Multi site setup - Update title for entry 1 site only

Tags: localization, multi-site, custom-fieldtype, element

My setup:

Craft 3 installation with a multi-site setup. 3 languages, all enabled.

I have a custom plugin with a custom element type, FooBar that extends the Element class and a custom FooBar field type allowing me to link to an FooBar entry.

I've created 3 FooBar entries, one in each site. If I edit one of the FooBar entries, only that entries title updates. That all works fine.

I have a Single with a relation field linked to the FooBar field, with one of the FooBar entries selected.

All pretty standard relation setup.

If I edit the Single but click on the Foobar entry title, the slideout panel opens allowing me to edit FooBar entry...That's fine. Expected functionality...

When I click save in the slideout panel, the FooBar entry is saved, again as expected but the title value is also updated across all 3 sites. From what I can gather, its because propagation is happening.

How do I update the FooBar entry in the current site only, stopping propagation (basically not updating across all 3 sites) ?

Saving an element within a slideout panel is core Craft functionality, My beforeSave event listener on FooBar element is not firing.

So is there another event, or something that I've missed where I can prevent the FooBar entry from being updated across all 3 site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean propagation, can you try this in your custom plugin/module?

```
Event::on(
    Elements::class,
    Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    static function (ElementEvent $e): void {
        // Skip propagating entries/elements
        if ($e->element->propagating) {
            return;
        }
    }
);
```

In fact, you can use this in any other event where the element is propagated